# Javascript Engine Simulator Module Not Producing Sound

Tags: javascript, three.js, web-audio-api

I'm using a JS Engine Noise Simulator module [here](https://github.com/Antonio-R1/engine-sound-generator).
When I start it up, it all seems to work from the logs in the console, but when I open the page and press play, no sound comes through.

Here's some of the code I used:

```
...

import * as THREE from 'three';

import {SoundGeneratorAudioListener, SineWaveSoundGenerator, EngineSoundGenerator} from './sound_generator_worklet.js';

var loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
loadingManager.onLoad = function () {
   moduleInit ();
};

listener = new SoundGeneratorAudioListener();
EngineSoundGenerator.load(loadingManager, listener);

soundCarEngine = new EngineSoundGenerator({listener: listener, parameters: {cylinders: 4,

                                 intakeWaveguideLength: 100,
                                 exhaustWaveguideLength: 100,
                                 extractorWaveguideLength: 100,

                                 intakeOpenReflectionFactor: 0.01,
                                 intakeClosedReflectionFactor: 0.95,

                                 exhaustOpenReflectionFactor: 0.01,
                                 exhaustClosedReflectionFactor: 0.95,
                                 ignitionTime: 0.016,

                                 straightPipeWaveguideLength: 128,
                                 straightPipeReflectionFactor: 0.01,

                                 mufflerElementsLength: [10, 15, 20, 25],
                                 action: 0.1,

                                 outletWaveguideLength: 5,
                                 outletReflectionFactor: 0.01}});
function rpmManager(j) {
    return new Proxy(JSON.parse ('{"watch":' + j + '}'), {
        set: function(target, property, value) {
            soundCarEngine.worklet.parameters.get('rpm').value = value;
            target[property] = value;
        }
    });
}
rpm = rpmManager(1)
```

How would I get the sound working?
Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Look at the docs again. It says you need to add the listener to the camera, and then add the generator to an `Object3D` and then trigger the `play()` function. I don't see any of that in your code. Look at `.htm` files in the `/src/engine_sound_generator
/` folder for examples. (Personally, the demos didn't produce any sound for me, either.)

Comment: (Disregard my last comment, I had my volume accidentally muted, and the examples do produce sound.)